# Is there such a thing as a "PostgreSQL-SQL-to-OtherDB-SQL" converter in PHP, or at all?

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL exclusively. I have no plans to ever change this. However, I recognize that other people are not me, and they instead use MySQL, MS SQL, IBM SQL, SQLite SQL, Oracle SQL and ManyOthers SQL. I'm aware that they have different names in reality.

My queries look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $1;
UPDATE table SET col = $1 WHERE col = $2;
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);
```

My database wrapper functions currently support only PostgreSQL, by internally calling the `pg_*` functions.

I wish to support "the other databases" too. This would involve (the trivial part) to make my wrapper functions able to interact with the other databases by using the PHP functions for those.

The **difficult part** is to reconstruct the PostgreSQL-flavor SQL queries from the application into something that works identically yet will be understood by the other SQL database in use, such as MySQL. This obviously involves highly advanced parsing, analysis and final creation of the final query string. For example, this PostgreSQL SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col ILIKE $1 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

... will be turned into WeirdSQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col ISEQUALTOKINDA %1 ORDER BY rnd() LIMIT 1;
```

I don't require support from any other input SQL flavor than PostgreSQL, but the output must be "all the big SQL database vendors".

Has anyone even attempted this? Or is it something that is never gonna happen as free software but might exist as a commercial offering? It sounds like it would be a thing. It would be insanely useful, and "crazier" projects have been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC uses its own syntax on top on the database's syntax. ODBC drivers are required to convert ODBC parameter markers (`?`) to whatever the database uses, and to translate [escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/odbc-escape-sequences) for certain elements that are likely to have a non-standard syntax in the DB (time/GUID/interval literals, LIKE escape character, outer joins, procedure calls, function calls).

However, most escape sequences are optional, and this does not help with other syntax differences, such as the `LIMIT 1`.

ODBC drivers provide a [long list of information about SQL syntax details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function#supported-sql), but it is the application's job to construct queries that conform to those restrictions, and not all differences can be described by this list. In practice, most ODBC applications restrict themselves to a commonly supported subset of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

[jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) is a Java library that aims to hide differences between databases. It has [its own SQL grammar](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-grammar/) which tries to be compatible with everything (but parameter markers must be the JDBC `?`), and generates DB-specific SQL from that.

There is an [online translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/), which generates the following from your query for Oracle:

```
select *
from table
where lower(cast(col as varchar2(4000))) like lower(cast(:1 as varchar2(4000)))
order by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
fetch next 1 rows only
```